# Converting G Force data to rotation?

Tags: python, math, 3d, accelerometer, blender

I've been playing around with an accelerometer with 3 axis: X, Y and Z. It says on the [supplier's site](http://www.parallax.com/tabid/768/ProductID/97/Default.aspx) that it measures gravitational force.

I'm sending this data to the blender games engine where I am rotating a cube in real time depending on the data values coming from the accelerometer. However the values coming through don't seem to match up.

On each axis the accelerometer spits out values from -700 to 700 on each axis and I need to convert these values to something I can use in Blender. My maths knowledge is not up to scratch so I don't know where to start with this one.

If anybody could shed some light on this, that would be great.

Many thanks
Will

**EDIT**
Currently I'm using a bit of python code to convert the rotation values to a matrix:

```
def reorient(alpha, beta, gamma):
  a = math.cos(alpha) 
  b = math.sin(alpha) 
  c = math.cos(beta) 
  d = math.sin(beta) 
  e = math.cos(gamma) 
  f = math.sin(gamma)    
  ad = a*d 
  bd = b*d 
  matrix = [[c*e, -a*f+b*d*e, b*f+a*d*e], [c*f, a*e+b*d*f, -b*e+a*d*f], [-d, b*c, a*c]]
  return matrix
```

I am then using setOrientation(matrix) to affect the rotation of the cube. However I am currently throwing the wrong values into the matrix reorient() function

Comment: Is the cube spinning in the first place? You are using the accelerometer to change the speed of rotation? Or is the cube stationary and you want to change its rotation (position)?

Comment: The cube is originally stationary, I'm using the accelerometer to change the cube's rotation. So for example, when I rotate the accelerometer, the cube should rotate in the same way

Comment: OK, but is it the speed and direction of rotation to impart that is important, or the final position of the cube?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, really I need the final position of the cube. But I guess the direction of rotation is important too. If you imagine someone holding an object in front of the screen. Rotating the object and at the same time, the object should be visualised in exactly the same way on the screen. It doesn't really matter about the speed of rotation, it should follow the position of the object exactly. Sorry I'm not the best at explaining things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the measured acceleration to find the direction of gravitational pull (ie, down). If you are moving the accelerometer, apart from just turning it, there will be some additional force; think of the accelerometer having a pendulum weight handing from it, as you move it the pendulum sways (although in this case it would be a very short, fast-reacting pendulum?). You could try doing some sort of movement compensation, but it might be simpler to just try to keep the sensor in a fixed location.

**Edit:** ok, it looks like I totally misread the question - you want to know *how* to do the rotation in a script?

It looks like each Blender object has three properties (.RotX, .RotY, .RotZ) which contain the current values (in radians) and a method (.rot(new_rotx, new_roty, new_rotz)) which performs a rotation (see documentation at http://www.blender.org/documentation/249PythonDoc/Object.Object-class.html). I am currently looking at how the rotations are applied; more shortly.

**Edit2:** it looks like the angles are specified as Euler angles (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles); they give some conversion matrices. It also looks like your accelerometer data is underconstrained (you need one more constraint, specifying rotation about the 'down' direction - maybe some sort of inertial 'least distance from previous position' calculation?)

**Edit3:** there is a sample script which may be helpful; on my machine it is at C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender.blender\scripts\object_random_loc_sz_rot.py  It shows how to get the currently selected object and tweak its rotation. Hope that helps!

**Edit4:** for sake of discussion, here is some sample code; it may be a bit redundant (I haven't worked in Blender before) and it doesn't *solve* the problem, but it will at least give us a common basis for further discussion ;-)

```
#!BPY

"""
Name: 'Set rotation by accelerometer'
Blender: 249
Group: 'Object'
Tooltip: 'Set the selected objects rotation by accelerometer'
"""

__bpydoc__=\
'''
This script sets the selected objects rotation by accelerometer.
'''

from Blender import Draw, Scene
import math

def reorient(alpha, beta, gamma):
    a = math.cos(alpha)
    b = math.sin(alpha)
    c = math.cos(beta)
    d = math.sin(beta)
    e = math.cos(gamma)
    f = math.sin(gamma)

    ad = a*d
    bd = b*d

    return = [
        [c*e, -a*f+b*d*e, b*f+a*d*e],
        [c*f, a*e+b*d*f, -b*e+a*d*f],
        [-d,  b*c,        a*c      ]
    ]

def getAccel():
    # test stub -
    # need to get actual values from accelerometer here
    dx = -700
    dy = 100
    dz = 250
    return (dx,dy,dz)

def normalize(vec):
    "Return scaled unit vector"
    x,y,z = vec
    mag = (x*x + y*y + z*z)**0.5
    return (x/mag, y/mag, z/mag)

def main():
    scn = Scene.GetCurrent()
    try:
        obj = scn.objects.context
        euler = (obj.RotX, obj.RotY, obj.RotZ)
    except AttributeError:
        return

    down = normalize(getAccel())
    matrix = None
    # do something here to find new rotation-matrix
    #   based on euler and down
    # then

    if matrix:
        obj.setOrientation(matrix)
    else:
        # test value:
        # if reorient() is working properly, the
        # object's rotation should not change!
        obj.setOrientation(reorient(*euler))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you're on the right track. Currently I'm using a bit of python code to convert the rotation values to a matrix:

def reorient(alpha, beta, gamma):
 a = math.cos(alpha)
 b = math.sin(alpha)
 c = math.cos(beta)
 d = math.sin(beta)
 e = math.cos(gamma)
 f = math.sin(gamma) 
 ad = a*d
 bd = b*d
 matrix = [[c*e, -a*f+b*d*e, b*f+a*d*e], [c*f, a*e+b*d*f, -b*e+a*d*f], [-d, b*c, a*c]]
 return matrix

I am then using setOrientation(matrix) to affect the rotation of the cube. However I am currently throwing the wrong values into the matrix reorient() function

Comment: Dammit, stackoverflow doesn't keep the formatting in comments, I've added an edit with this comment above to the main question so it's easier to read

Comment: Thanks Hugh, is there a way I can access that python file. It's on your local computer. I don't think I can access it?

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your last comment, you're saying I should have the same file on my computer! Cheers :D

Comment: I've been trying this code, but I have no idea what to do in the area which says "do something here to find new rotation-matrix based on euler and down then" :(

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you can use the accelerometers to correctly determine which way is 'up'.  We can call that vector **N**.  It seems to me that you want the 'up' direction of your cube to align with **N**.  As already mentioned, that leaves the cube free to spin, but you can still find a rotation matrix that might accomplish what you're going for, but you need to account for two separate cases or else you'll have a singularity in the solution.  I'll assume that 'Z' is 'up' on the cube.

If you treat the three accelerometer values as a vector and normalize it (to get **N**), you've got the new 'Z' axis portion of your rotation matrix so that a vector pointed in the z direction will now align with the 'up' vector.

```
| a d N.x |   |0|   |N.x|
| b e N.y | * |0| = |N.y|
| c f N.z |   |1|   |N.z|
```

So we need to decide what to do with a-f.  One common thing to do is this: if **N** is pointing mostly along the original 'Z' axis, then make the new 'Y' axis portion of the matrix be **M** = **N** cross **X**:

```
d =  0
e =  N.z
f = -N.y
```

Normalize **M** and then find the 'X' axis portion of the matrix: **L** = **M** cross **N**.  Normalize **L**.

If **N** is not pointing mostly along the 'Z' axis (N.z < .707), then you find the new 'Y' axis portion as **M** = **N** cross **Z**.  Normalize **M** and find **L** = **M** cross **N** and, finally, normalize **L**.

---

Edit:

So we have our three accelerometer values: A.x, A.y, A.z.  First step is to normalize them:

```
a = sqrt(A.x*A.x + A.y*Ay + A.z*A.z);      and then 
N.x = A.x/a;  N.y = A.y/a;  N.z = A.z/a;
```

We assume that if `N == [0, 0, 1]` then the correct rotation matrix is the identity matrix.  If *N* doesn't point directly along the *z-axis*, then we want to form a matrix that will rotate the z-axis of the cube so that it lines up with *N*.

Comment: Hi JCooper, I've been looking at your answer over and over again over the last few days. But I am just getting my head around vectors and I'm finding it really hard to understand! Would you be able to post some example code, I might be able to understand that better :)

Comment: I started trying to clarify, but I'm not sure exactly what you don't understand.  Do you know how to compute a cross product?